# Does necessary equivalence imply identity?

Tags: logic

If it is impossible to do *x* without doing *y*, and it is also impossible to do *y* without doing *x*, does that mean that x and y are the same thing, or could such a relation between them exist while they're two different things?

Comment: There are multiple senses of identity and your question helps to highlight that.

Answer (score 1):

Could be different. What you're asking about is the mathematically defined difference between a poset and a preorder. Both are characterized by a ≤ relation, typically called "weaker than". For a poset, a≤b and b≤a implies a=b, which is called the antisymmetry condition. For a preorder, a≤b and b≤a doesn't imply equality. You can google those words for some examples of preorders that aren't posets.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question epistemic or ontological? If a token is identical to another token of the same type, they are still distinct tokens but we may know of them that they are equivalent and replaceable, such as a penny, nickel or quarter.

[(X → Y) ∧ (Y → X)] → [(X ∧ Y) V̲ (¬X ∧ ¬Y)]

If y whenever x and x whenever y, then either x and y are both true or x and y are both false, but this is not a comment upon whether or not x is y and y is x.

[image]

Is necessary equivalence sufficient for identity. No.

Does necessary equivalence necessarily imply identity? No.

Is necessary equivalence sufficient and necessary for identity? No.

Is it redundant to postulate that a thing is identical with itself? Yes.

Are any two things separated in spacetime the same thing? No.